# Solving linear equations with an unknown constant?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an augmented matrix in the from:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & h  & -5\\
2 & -8 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If I take `-2*Row1 + Row2`  I end up with
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & h & -5\\
0 & -2h-8 & 16
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My question is two-fold, (a) is this the correct strategy for solving this type of problem and (b) where do I go from here?

My first inclination is to solve for `(-2h-8)x_2 = 16`

I am not looking for the direct answer just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Why did you stop halfway through? What would happen if you kept on going?

Comment: A general principle you can follow: a system of linear equations is not solvable only if, when you reduce it to triangular form (as you have done correctly), one of the equations looks like $0 = c$, where $c$ is not zero - in other words, in the augmented form you get a row that is all zeros except the last entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just fine. Be aware that when you solve $$(-2h-8)x_2=16$$ for $x_2,$ you will need to take care that you are not dividing by $0$ (not all values of $h$ will allow you to solve this equation, so in such cases, your system has no solution). Once you've done that, back-substitute into the equation corresponding to the first row, and solve for $x_1.$